# "Check" or "check out" or "check on"?

Tags: grammar

> Mary was very busy. That, however, didn't stop her from checking
>   (on/out) Mrs. Johnsons' research.

Is it necessary to add on or out in cases like this? If so, why?

Comment: Why would you think it is necessary? Or not necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Mary was very busy. That, however, didn't stop her from **checking** Mrs. Johnson’s research.
>   Mary was very busy. That, however, didn't stop her from **checking out** Mrs. Johnson’s research.

These both mean that Mary reviewed Mrs. Johnson's research.

But when you say:

> Mary was very busy. That, however, didn't stop her from **checking on** Mrs. Johnson’s research.

this means Mary checked on the status/progress of Mrs. Johnson's research, but not the contents of it.

Comment: Thanks. What's more common? Checking or checking out in this case?

Comment: I would say "checking" is better in this scenario. "checking out" has the connotation of "*checking out* the babes", or perhaps "*checking out* Mrs. Johnson".