# The use of "check" or "check on" in context

Tags: difference, phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

Tell me please if I need to use *check* or *check on* in the following context.

> I am not sure if the facts he cited are true, so I had better **check**/**check on** them.

If both are correct there, then what is the difference?

Comment: I would use **check** in this instance. **Check on** someone or something means to look at them to make sure they are OK, or to monitor their progress - but it can also be used in the sense of 'make sure something is accurate', so it wouldn't be wrong in your sentence.

Comment: I think the use of "had" there is incorrect. You are saying that you are not sure of something now which means you haven't checked the facts yet.

Comment: 'Had' is correct. 'I had better [do something]' means 'I should [do something]', or 'I would be wise or sensible to [do something]'. To say 'I better [do something]' instead is informal, conversational,  or dialect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Check" or "check out" or "check on"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39384/check-or-check-out-or-check-on)

Comment: Note that ***to check out*** is a true "transitive phrasal verb", so an object pronoun can be spliced in as *...so I'd better check **them** out*. But you can't do that with *...so I'd better check **them up*** (invalid). That would require the object to be placed after the verb *with a preposition*, as in *...so I'd better check up **on them**.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Check on X* means make sure X is OK.

*Check X* means to get the current state of X, but you typically wouldn't do something unless X is doing something wrong.  Because of that implication it's often interchangeable with *check on*.

*Check on X* is probably a bit more typically used if X is some distance from you or some time will pass before you actually check.

> Check on the food in an hour.
>
> Check the food now.

but switching these around isn't incorrect and doesn't sound strange.

In the sense of going to someone's house and making sure someone is OK, you'd almost always use *check on* and not *check*.  Not using *on* in the following sentences sounds a bit like you mean "check" in the sense of "medically examine":

> Check on Margaret when you get into town.
>
> Check on my cat when you get home.

---

Facts are not people, so you'd say *check* and not *check on*.